# My PHP code to delete a row from an SQLite table using PDO not working

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

The following block of code is not working to do what it is meant to do.

I have confirmed that the DELETE statement (in the second line) works directly on the command line for sqlite3 where OutputID = 1

```
$myPDO = new PDO("sqlite:$dbpath");
$stmt = $myPDO->prepare("DELETE FROM Output WHERE ID = :OutputID");
$stmt->bindParam(':OutputID', $OutputID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

Expected result is 1 but I get 0

Comment: Where did you set `$OutputID`?

Comment: Please verify the value of $OutputID. Make sure it contains the expected value. I don't see anything wrong in the above code. Pretty sure $OutputID is equal to 0 or NULL ...

Comment: I set $OutputID before the PDO object declaration and confirmed that it is 1

Comment: Are you sure it is ID and not id? Also can you tell us if any errors are thrown?

Comment: It is ID and I just looked at the errors thrown: the database was read-only, so I moved it into a directory with 777 permissions, and now it works :)

Comment: Thanks, all, for your help.  The suggestion about the errors thrown helped.  I am new to this, you see!

Answer (score 0):

The error (gotten by capturing $myPDO->errorInfo(); which returns an array) was that the database was read-only, so I moved the database file into a directory with 777 permissions (I am working in Linux environment, by the way) and changed the permissions of the database file to 777 also. I modified the database path in the code accordingly and now it works!